# Flash Builder code completion not working when targeting different player API

Tags: flash, apache-flex, flash-builder

I'm using FlashBuilder 4.6 to build an application that targets different Flash Players. I mainly use the 4.5.1 SDK because I want to allow users with older Flash Players to be able to use my application while benefiting from the Spark framework. SDK 4.6 requires FP 11.2, so that throws out too many users.

That means I can target Flash Players from version 10.2 and up. My application uses audio and video, so I want users that have newer Flash Players to benefit from the newer features. For example, 10.3 supports Acoustic Echo Cancellation. So, if my HTML wrapper detects 10.3 or up, the version with AEC is loaded.

To be able to target FP 10.3's new API's, I had to download playerglobal.swc for 10.3 and put it in the libs directory of my SDK. And set the compiler option 'use specific version' to 10.3.0 and I added the compiler directive -swf-version=12. That works fine, the application compiles and the features work.

However, syntax highlighting and code completion in Flash Builder still do not seem to know about the new classes and methods in 10.3, for example Microphone.getEnhancedMicrophone(). So, it seems that the code completion module doesn't use playerglobal.swc to get it's information from.

My question is this: how can I tell FlashBuilder's code completion about the newer player API?

Comment: Did you replace the playerglobal.swc on your build path?

Comment: To add to that, you need to go to Project Properties>Actionscript Build Path>Library path and click your playerglobal.swc and edit the path to the correct one. http://swfhead.com/blog/?p=709

Answer (score 0):

Apache Flex 4.9.0 released a few weeks back will allow you to target Flash Player 10.2 and up.

Look in README for instructions on how to compile for other any versions of the Flash Player (by default it's 11.1). There are also some scripts in the ide directory in the develop branch (in SVN) that can make setting the minimum Flash Player version a little easier.

Apache Flex 4.9.0 can be downloaded from:
http://flex.apache.org/

But I suggest you use the installer to download and create an SDK. It can be found here:
http://flex.apache.org/installer.html

The code completion should work and is based off what is contained in your flex-config.xml (in the frameworks directory of the SDK). Check that these two lines are correct.

```
<!-- Specifies the minimum player version that will run the compiled SWF. -->
<target-player>11.1<target-player>

<!-- Specifies the version of the compiled SWF -->
<swf-version>14<swf-version>
```

ie Set to 10.3 and 12 in your case.